# command block - "you must be a player to use this command!'

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm getting this output message in the command block interface when I'm trying to execute an automatic cinematic with the plugin "CPCameraStudioReborn":

> You must be a player to use this command!

I even tried to use `/execute` like so:

```
execute @p ~ ~ ~ /cam start 3s cinema
```

Is there a way to run this command automatically? Like spawning an armor stand entity which would perform it? Or even using a plugin like "citizen" to make an NPC do it for me?

Comment: I don't think this is going to be possible given `execute @p` failed, since I assume behind the scenes the command is being executed by the command block at the position of @p, so this is probably the closest you can get without like, changing the source code of the mod

Comment: i've searched the whole internet for a plugin to do automatic cutscene but it does not seems to be a popular request, so trying to figure out how to do that with this one is my only option here since i don't have the knowledge to modify the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the plugin 'Essentials', try the following:

```
/sudo <your playername> c:/cam start 3s cinema
```

Minecraft's default 'execute' command does not always work with plugins.

**Differences between 'execute' and 'sudo':**

While 'execute' runs the command **as console** with the **player's position**, 'sudo' runs the command **as if the player would have run it**.

Answer (score 0):

If you get that error message, then the command can't work in a command block.

You can try to contact the mod author to add automation features, but until then, you'll have to try to automate it some other way, for example using a mouse/keyboard macro program.